# Mesos slave not 'Running' multiple executors simultaneously

Tags: distributed-computing, executor, mesos

I am using Mesos to distribute a bunch of tasks to different machines (mesos-slaves). 
Here is what happens: 
1. My scheduler gets resource offers and accepts it.
2. Mesos stages multiple executors on the same mesos-slaves (each slave has 4 cpus)
3. Only ONE executor enters the 'Running' state on each of the slaves while the others are shown in 'Staging' state. 
4. Only after the current executor finishes execution the other executor starts running.

Given that I have 4 CPUs on each machine, shouldn't each slave be running 4 executors simultaneously? Each executor requires 1 CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your tasks using the same executor id or different executor id? If the former, only one executor is launched by the slave and all the tasks are sent to that one executor. If your executor is designed to run multiple tasks you have to make sure that you are *not* blocking in the launchTask() callback, e.g., by running the actual task in the callback before returning from it. One way to design a multiple task executor is to use multi-threading or fork/execing subprocesses.

Comment: THanks for the reply. Yes, I am using the same executor id (default). Sorry I am new at it. How should I change the executor id (it currently says default)?